# SSH Remote Forwarding with two hops

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

How can I make ports forwarded or proxied by ssh available to machines other than the local machine?

e.g. machine A connecting to machine B (works)

```
ssh -L8080:some-service:8080 user@machine-B
```

machine C connecting to Machine B through Machine A's forwarded port (doesn't work)

```
curl machine-A:8080
```

I get

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to machine-A port 8080: Connection refused
```

machine A connecting to Machine B through machine A's forwarded port (does work)

```
curl 127.0.0.1:8080
```

Comment: How did you get an error about port 80 when you're trying to connect to port 8080? You dun goofed somewhere.

Comment: @wmarbut: then your curl command should also be `curl 127.0.0.1:8080`, right?

Comment: @Ale. yeah. sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `-g` option:

```
 -g      Allows remote hosts to connect to local forwarded ports.
```

So:

```
ssh -L8080:some-service:8080 -g user@machine-B
```